# how can i update a record without erasing the old one in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a trouble can you please help me? i am making a system in which user can update their grades. it is ok until i found a bug in which when ever a student updates a failing grade ex 5, when he tries to update it again the 5 will be erased which i would like to stay so that they can see if that student have failed that subject how can i make it stay?  i think what i needed is a script in which when a student have many grades in one subjects because of failure it can separate or identify the grades as different numbers. hope you understand what i needed.. Thx by the way.. hope you could help me..

Answer (score 2):

Have a table which contains (class_id, student_id, grade) and insert a second row with the second grade.

Comment: i think thats what i realy need but how can i create another row? Thx for your reply :)

Comment: The same way you created the first row -- an `INSERT` query!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not erase any valid entries from a database.

For you case, you should maintain a table where every grade is kept, irrespective of repeats.

When you would prepare the Grade Sheet, you would only select the entries that would give an updated Grade Sheet. If you need to make any changes, you would do it in the place where you prepare the Grade Sheet.

*I know Grade Sheet was never mentioned in your post, but I figure you would need to prepare them anyway :)*

Comment: can i possibly just create another row if the student has a failing grade so that the row i will create will be the row for his 2nd grade? hmnn for example GRADE:FAILED so i would create another row until he gets a passing grade. but i dont know how to add another row..

Comment: With the given columns, you will not be able to add another row since it would duplicate the entry if there is more than one fail grade. You may like to add another column that reflects the semester/term whatever is applicable. This way, you will never have two rows that are exact duplicate of one another (Unless a student takes the same course twice in the same term :) ).

Comment: sorry what i want to create is column not row.. i missed type above..i get what you are saying i will give it i try.. but how can i make another row or column? whenever a student has a failing grade? i get the logic now but i cant think of its code.. thx for your replies your a big help..

Comment: If we think of the system as a whole, whenever a student has a failing grade in a subject, you would prompt them to retake the course. When the Grade for that is available, you would enter a new row for that grade.

Comment: for example i am an it student i have 3 subject math english and programming my grade for math and english is pass and for programming is failed when i take the subject programming again and pass how can i possibly show that i failed at the first time and pass at my second try? thats my problem sorry for comsuming your time.

Comment: This is open community, so no question of consuming time :).
You see, you would be maintaining all the Grades earned. Now if a particular course appears twice, that means you have failed in an earlier attempt. That is why, it was necessary to add another column to track terms.

Comment: how can i possibly add another column? i know how to add another table but i dont know if it is possible to add only another column in that table

Comment: Please see here: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/378/add-a-column-to-an-existing-mysql-table/

Answer (score 0):

Building on previous answers, with more explicit data since I think you need it...

You probably have something like this now:

```
[student_id]  [class_id]  [grade_result]
    007          ABC           F
```

and if the student retakes the class, it overwrites that data. But you don't want that to happen. You want to store both. The solution is to add a date column...

```
[student_id]  [class_id]  [grade_result]  [class_date]
    007          ABC           F            2010-FALL
    007          ABC           B            2011-SPRING
```

Now your student can take the class as many times as (s)he pleases, and you've got a nice log of all results. Nothing is overwritten.

Note that `[class_date]` could be logged in a variety of formats. I'm not necessarily recommending you use the `YEAR-SEASON` example. I only chose that because it was most clear.

EDIT - also note that for these tables you'd only ever use `INSERT INTO...` queries, not the `UPDATE...` queries you're probably using now.

Answer (score 0):

[Dan Grossman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802060/how-can-i-update-a-record-without-erasing-the-old-one-in-php-and-mysql/4802075#4802075) is correct, and the MySQL and PHP manuals are your friends :-)

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php